# Spectrum of an Operator on a Banachspace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Claim: Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banachspace $\mathfrak{X}$. Denote $\sigma(A)$ as the spectrum of A. Let $\lambda$ be a point in the boundary of the $\sigma(A)$. Then there exist a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 0}\subset \mathfrak{X}$, $\|x_n\| = 1$ such that

$$(\lambda\mathbb{1} - A)x_n\rightarrow 0.$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Hint: $\sigma(A)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb C$, so $\partial \sigma(A)\subset \sigma(A)$.

Comment: @Math1000 sorry I still don't see it.

Comment: @Math1000 This means that $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ and therefore $(\lambda \mathbb{1} - A)$ is not invertible, so therefore the kernel is non trivial? But wouldn't this mean there is even an $x \in \mathfrak{X}$ such that $(\lambda \mathbb{1} - A) x = 0$

Comment: @Math1000 Ok I realize that this argument is only valid if $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum. If $\lambda$ is in the continues spectrum then I see that the sequence exists, now all that is left is the residual spectrum right?

Comment: If $\lambda\in\partial\sigma(A)$ then there exists a sequence $\lambda_n\subset\rho(A)$ with $\lambda_n\to\lambda$. Then what can we say about $\|(\lambda_n I-A)^{-1}\|$?

Comment: @Math1000 well the elements $(\lambda_n I -A)^{-1}$ exist and are bounded so the norm is finite. So are the $x_n = (\lambda_n I -A)^{-1}/||(\lambda_n I -A)^{-1}||$?

Comment: You should probably add that the $x_n$ should be unit vectors.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes thanks, this was actually given, I forgot to write it down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\lambda\in\partial\sigma(A)$, then there exists $\{ \lambda_n \} \subset\rho(A)$ that converges to $\lambda$. Suppose for the moment that the following holds for all $x$:
$$
               l(x)=\sup_{n}\|(\lambda_n I-A)^{-1}x\| < \infty.
$$
Then, by the uniform boundedness principle,
$$
           M=\sup_{n} \|(\lambda_n I -A)^{-1} \| < \infty.
$$
Hence, for $|\lambda-\lambda_n|M < 1$, it must hold that $\lambda I-A$ is invertible because $(\lambda_n I-A)$ is invertible and
\begin{align}
  (\lambda I-A)
     & = (\lambda-\lambda_n)I+(\lambda_n I-A)\\
     & = \{(\lambda-\lambda_n)(\lambda_nI-A)^{-1}+I\}(\lambda_n I-A)
\end{align}
This contradiction proves that the original assumption was false. Hence, there exists $x$ such that $\lim_{k} \|(\lambda_{n_k} I-A)^{-1}x\|=\infty$. Let
$$
     y_k = \|(\lambda_{n_k} I-A)^{-1}x\|^{-1}(\lambda_{n_k}I-A)^{-1}x.
$$
Then $\{ y_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of unit vectors for which
$$
     (\lambda I-A)y_k = (\lambda-\lambda_{n_k})y_k+\|(\lambda_{n_k}I-A)^{-1}x\|^{-1}x
$$
Hence, $\lim_{k}(\lambda I-A)y_k = 0$.